# Rails: Many to many database design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

***Model:***

Material
Manager

***Relationship***
One item needs to be approve by many managers.
One manager need to approve many items.

I do not know how to design a `many_to_many` relationship.
I planed to create a joined table like this

```
Model Approval:
item_id,
manager_id
```

The problem is that if I design model like this approval will have one manager or several managers, but the situation is that the number of managers could change all the time, so it is hard to set a certain number of managers in the model `Approval`.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :managers
end

class Manager < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :materials
end
```

migrations:

```
class CreateManagerssAndMaterials < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :managers do |t|

    end

    create_table :materials do |t|

    end

    create_table :managers_materials, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :manager, index: true
      t.belongs_to :material, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

You can find more here 
[rails migrations has_and_belogs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

for example in controller:

```
@material = Material.find(5)
@material.managers << [Manager.find(1), Manager.find(2)]
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to add foreign key to models? For example, add two manger with id 1 and id 2 , to material with id 5.
I hope to know how to use it in controller